# How can remove duplicate values from an associative array in PHP?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, associative-array

I have array that convert from JSON file. Data in this array is duplicate . How can I remove duplicate data ?

```
 
 Array
   (
       [0] => Array
           (

               [code] => A
               [children] => Array
                   (
                       [0] => Array
                           (

                               [code] => A-4
                               [children] => Array
                                   (
                                       [0] => Array
                                           (

                                               [code] => A-4-2
                                               [children] => Array
                                                   (
                                                   )

                                               [id] => 1224
                                               [name] => ALTERNATOR
                                           )

                                       [1] => Array
                                           (

                                               [code] => A-4-3
                                               [children] => Array
                                                   (
                                                   )

                                               [id] => 1225
                                               [name] => STARTER
                                           )

                                       [2] => Array
                                           (

                                               [code] => A-4-1
                                               [children] => Array
                                                   (
                                                   )

                                               [id] => 1223
                                               [name] => IGNITION COIL & SPARK PLUG
                                           )

                                       [3] => Array
                                           (

                                               [code] => A-4-4
                                               [children] => Array
                                                   (
                                                   )

                                               [id] => 1226
                                               [name] => VACUUM PUMP
                                           )

                                       [4] => Array
                                           (

                                               [code] => A-4-2
                                               [children] => Array
                                                   (
                                                   )

                                               [id] => 1224
                                               [name] => ALTERNATOR
                                           )

                                       [5] => Array
                                           (

                                               [code] => A-4-3
                                               [children] => Array
                                                   (
                                                   )

                                               [id] => 1225
                                               [name] => STARTER
                                           )

                                       [6] => Array
                                           (

                                               [code] => A-4-1
                                               [children] => Array
                                                   (
                                                   )

                                               [id] => 1223
                                               [name] => IGNITION COIL & SPARK PLUG
                                           )

                                       [7] => Array
                                           (

                                               [code] => A-4-4
                                               [children] => Array
                                                   (
                                                   )

                                               [id] => 1226
                                               [name] => VACUUM PUMP
                                           )

                                   )

                               [id] => 1183
                               [name] => Ignition
                           )

                   )

               [id] => 1171
               [name] => Engine/Cooling/Emission/Fuel
           )
       )
```

Output It should be like this

```
 
 Array
   (
       [0] => Array
           (

               [code] => A
               [children] => Array
                   (
                       [0] => Array
                           (

                               [code] => A-4
                               [children] => Array
                                   (
                                       [0] => Array
                                           (

                                               [code] => A-4-2
                                               [children] => Array
                                                   (
                                                   )

                                               [id] => 1224
                                               [name] => ALTERNATOR
                                           )

                                       [1] => Array
                                           (

                                               [code] => A-4-3
                                               [children] => Array
                                                   (
                                                   )

                                               [id] => 1225
                                               [name] => STARTER
                                           )

                                       [2] => Array
                                           (

                                               [code] => A-4-1
                                               [children] => Array
                                                   (
                                                   )

                                               [id] => 1223
                                               [name] => IGNITION COIL & SPARK PLUG
                                           )

                                       [3] => Array
                                           (

                                               [code] => A-4-4
                                               [children] => Array
                                                   (
                                                   )

                                               [id] => 1226
                                               [name] => VACUUM PUMP
                                           )


                                   )

                               [id] => 1183
                               [name] => Ignition
                           )

                   )

               [id] => 1171
               [name] => Engine/Cooling/Emission/Fuel
           )
       )
```

Comment: what have you tried, where is your code?

Comment: I ' ve used   array_unique  but It's didn't work

Answer (score 1):

Use [`array_unique`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) function

```
$array['children'] = array_unique($array['children']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **array_unique** to resolve your issue:

```
$array['children'] = array_unique($array['children'], SORT_REGULAR);
// SORT_REGULAR means compare items normally (don't change types)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested my code.. Try this :-

```
 $array = //put the array in this variable
 foreach($array as $mkey $arr){
     foreach($arr['children'] as $skey => $arrchild){
         $array[$mkey]['children'][$skey]['children']  = array_unique($arrchild['children']);
   }
}
echo "<pre>"; print_r($array); die;
```

Hope it helps!